# Показать элемент при наведении на другой, и скрыть при специальном условии

Tags: html, css

У меня есть 2 независимых элемента.

Первый это горизонтальная навигация, с кнопками.
Второй это скрытое меню. Отдельный блок который по структуре верстки в отдельной секции.

Я хочу что бы при наведение на кнопку в горизонтальном меню отобразился другой блок, и был видимым до тех пор, пока пользователь держит курсор на элементе горизонтального меню, либо на самом элементе, который выпал

**Самый простой способ прояснить мой вопрос используя скриншоты:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выше скрин с горизонтальным меню, в состояние спокойствия.

Далее навожу мышкой на элемент **"Outlet"**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видите, отображается полупрозрачное меню под навигацией.

Я хочу его скрыть только в том случае, если пользователь не водит по самому полупрозрачному меню мышкой.

Я пробовал реализовать это по такому примеру:

```
$(".Hover-Link").hover(function(){
    $(".MainMenu").fadeIn();
});

$(".Hover-Link").mouseout(function(){
    $(".MainMenu").fadeOut();
});
```

Но только в этой реализации меню скрывается сразу как пользователь перевел курсор с кнопки в навигации на меню, и таким образом он не успевает с ним взаимодействовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно затормозить закрытие меню, на доли секунды, и если в этот промежуток пользователь наедет мышкой на само меню, то не закрывать его:

```
var timeoutId = undefined;

$(".Hover-Link").hover(function(){
  if (timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = undefined;
  } else {
    $(".MainMenu").fadeIn();
  }
});

$(".Hover-Link").mouseout(function(){
  timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
    timeoutId = undefined;
    $(".MainMenu").fadeOut();
  }, 16);
});

$(".MainMenu").hover(function(){
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  timeoutId = undefined;
});

$(".MainMenu").mouseout(function(){
  timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
    timeoutId = undefined;
    $(".MainMenu").fadeOut();
  }, 16);
});
```

Comment: Оба варианта являлись правильными. Ваш вариант надо было бы изменить как ответили в предыдущем ответе - событиями mouseenter и mouseleave. Однако правильным отмечу все таки ваш ответ, так как через таймаут реализация более правильная, поскольку нет скачков в открытии меню, как к примеру в варианте ниже. Если быстро перевести с одного элемента меню на другой то в варианте ниже происходило залагивание, и меню закрывалось. Здесь все ок! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Прячьте меню не сразу, как ушла мышь, а через таймаут. Причем после наступления таймаута, проверяйте, а не находится ли курсор над меню.

А в самом меню заведите флаг, который будет устанавливаться при попадании мыши в меню и сбрасываться при покидании.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.bar').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).data('lock', true);
    $('.menu').fadeIn();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).data('lock', false);
    setTimeout(function() {
      const menu = $('.menu');
      if (!menu.data('lock'))
        menu.fadeOut();
    }, 100);
  });
  
  $('.menu').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).data('lock', true);
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    const el = $(this);
    el.data('lock', false);
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (!$('.bar').data('lock'))
        el.fadeOut();
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

```css
.bar {
  background-color: #ffefef;
}
.menu {
  background-color: #efefef;
  display:none;
}

.menu div {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">Menu bar</div>
<div class="menu">
  Menu
  <div>
    Sub Menu 1
    <div>Sub Menu 1.1</div>
    <div>Sub Menu 1.2</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Sub Menu 2
    <div>Sub Menu 2.1</div>
    <div>Sub Menu 2.2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Суть я понял, но дело в том что сам элемент menu имеет множество вложенных элементов. И ваш код кажется надо как то скорректировать, так как как только я наведу на child элемент меню оно закрывается.

Comment: Вот пример. При наведение на вложенные элементы меню закрывается http://jsfiddle.net/wgx69thf/2/

Comment: @WhoIsDT Извините, моя ошибка. Вместо `hover`/`mouseout` нужно использовать `mouseenter`/`mouseleave`. Детали [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave)